# How to track changes (and most important read) really big files in Java efficiently

Tags: java, file, file-io, bigdata

I have a big log file in text form, created by a 3rd party app. Unfortunately my file is 150MB, others may have even bigger files, depending on the day they started logging. Since the file is created by a 3rd party application I can't really modify it in any way (remove some of it's oldest content for example).

What I want to do is keep track of the file size and be notified when there is a new line added (thus the size of the file is altered) and then read this line (it will be the last line).

I know when I want to keep track of the changes, it doesn't have to be a constant update, but when the user has the application minimized in the tray. Essentially, I want to notify the user about changes in the state of the application when he dcan't see them.

Now I am tracking the differences in the size of the file using

```
File file = new File("filepath"); 
file.length();
```

As far as I understand this doesn't load the file into the memory so it's not that much of a performance drop.

If I am right **what is the most efficient way to read the `last line` of that file?**

Replace efficiency with "as low performance drop as possible". I don't mind a 2 or 3 seconds delay between the actual event being logged to the file and the user being notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DirectoryWatcher to be notified of a change to a directory or file.  You can use RandomAccessFile to wind to any position e.g. where you read up to last by byte, and read the bytes from that point.  You can use the deprecated readLine() method if your particularly care about encoding.

Otherwise I suggest you copy whole lines to a buffer e.g. ByteArrayOutputStream and decode this using the right encoding.

There reason you want to copy first is that youc an get incomplete lines or even incomplete multi-byte characters which Bufferedreader doesn't handle particularly well.